# How to create an encrypted partition and how does Linux then decrypt it

Tags: linux, debian, partition, encryption, dm-crypt

I'm still very much in the learning phase of Linux especially for the use in embedded systems.

My intention is to create a separate encrypted partition on an SD card, possibly by using dm-crypt. This partition will be in a separate partition to the one that the Linux image is stored on.

What I don't understand tho, when Linux accesses this partition and decrypts it, how does the decryption happen?

Which leads me to my main question, If I then load a completely new Linux system onto the Linux partition, will the new Linux still be able to decrypt that separate partition?

Comment: So as long as you do not erase the encrypted partition when you reinstall the OS on the other partition or reformat the disk you can reuse the encrypted partition as long as the disk still works. Decryption happens as you configure it, whether by keyfile or password or a combination of both, automatically or manually unlocking the partition.

Comment: I will say this is a broad topic, this site works best with specific questions and answers. Do some research on encryption and edit your question to involve a more focused topic such as an issue you have with a specific implementation of dm-crypt or errors you are encountering while setting what you wish up.

Comment: @kemotep . I am trying to understand if encrypting a partition with dm-crypt is really what I need. I thought maybe the encrypted partition would be tied to a specific OS in that only the exact same OS that encrypted the partition could decrypt it, maybe by using private/public keys. If I would load on a new OS to the OS partition, I was wondering if I can still decrypt the encrypted partition in the same way the old OS decrypted it.

Comment: No, a container encrypted with dm-crypt is not tied to the operating system. It also doesn't use public key authentication (private/public key). Their home page and FAQ is likely to answer any questions you may have about it; It's quite detailed: https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/wikis/DMCrypt